# How can I check whether a parameter isa Symbol?

Tags: ruby

The question is in the title.

My parameter can be either a string or a symbol and depending upon which it is I want to perform different actions.  Is there a way to check for this in Ruby?

Comment: Needing to check the type of an object in Ruby is a code smell. It's a sign you should refactor how your parameters are coming in.

Comment: I agree but this is a pretty simple view helper and the reason I am doing it, is so that I can send in my parameters in any valid form without causing an exception.

Comment: You could just to arg= arg.to_sym, to ensure, that your argument is in the right form. This does work for strings, but not for all possible arguments types.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
def foo(arg)
  if arg.is_a?(Symbol)
    do_symbol_stuff
  else
    do_string_stuff
  end
end
```

Comment: There is a nicer way to write this. Use the Class#=== method like this: Symbol === arg. It is much more readable.

Comment: That's a matter of taste of course, but personally I think "if arg is a symbol" reads more naturally than "if arg equals equals equals symbol".

Answer (score 2):

Another solution

```
def foo(arg)
  case arg
    when Symbol
      do symbol stuff
    when String
      do string stuff
    else
      do error stuff
  end
end
```